# How to add an overlay that modifies a Kustomization?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Here's my directory structure:

```
|- base
|  |- file1.yaml
|  |- file2.yaml
|  |- kustomization.yaml
|- overlays
   |- nofile2
      |- kustomization.yaml
      |- nofile2.yaml
```

`base/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - file1.yaml
  - file2.yaml
```

Desired behavior: when I apply the Kustomization in `overlays/nofile2`, I want to run the kustomization in `base`, but I want to remove `file2.yaml` from the resources. So, I tried this for `overlays/nofile2/kustomization.yaml`:

```
resources:
  - ../../base
patches:
  - target:
      kind: Kustomization
    path: nofile2.yaml
```

And in `nofile2.yaml`:

```
- op: delete
  path: /resources/1
```

But when I run `kustomize build overlays/nofile2`, the output is identical to when I build the `base` kustomization.

What am I doing wrong here? And is there a better way to kustomize kustomizations?